# Dynamic jQuery Waypoints Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-waypoints

I'm struggling with the syntax for a loop that goes through and dynamically sets jQuery Waypoints.

Currently I have this code -

HTML Markup

For each 'process-anchor' I want to create a jQuery Waypoint

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="process-anchor-1"></div>
   <div class="process-anchor-2"></div>
   <div class="process-anchor-3"></div>
   <div class="process-anchor-4"></div>
   <div class="process-anchor-5"></div>
</div>

<div class="image-list">
    <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code (currently)

```
var process_fixed_anchor_1 = $('.process-anchor-1').waypoint({
      handler: function(direction) {
         $(".process-image-1").toggleClass("fade-in");
      }
});
```

I want to run through and create waypoints however the amount of anchor DIV's may change. How could I edit the above code to be dynamic so I don't have to be specific every time?

Thanks,

DIM3NSION

Comment: Can you put more of your code into your question? Your markup? Also, i'm not seeing the actual loop you're running through in your code, just two vars being set and `waypoint()` init, but as it's written, it will only run once.

Comment: Hi Lionel, I've edited my answer to hopefully alleviate any confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still just a bit unclear on what you're trying to accomplish, but here's how I would dynamically assign waypoints to a page given an unknown number of anchor divs:

#### Markup

I have added `class="trigger-anchor"` to your anchor divs with the hopes of finding a more approachable way to target those divs. Also put a common class on your `process-image-*` rather than letting them all be unique.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="process-anchor-1" class="trigger-anchor">
        <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process-anchor-2" class="trigger-anchor">
        <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process-anchor-3" class="trigger-anchor">
        <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process-anchor-4" class="trigger-anchor">
        <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="process-anchor-5" class="trigger-anchor">
        <div class="process-image"><img src="test.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

I'll run an `.each()` on the elements where `class="trigger-anchor"` to build by waypoints. This way I don't have to declare `var loops = 5;` or anything like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Wait until our DOM is ready
    $( document ).ready( function() {

        // Keep Track of how many we make and store 
        // our instances in an array to access if 
        // we need to later
        var anchors = array();

        $( '.trigger-anchor' ).each( function() {

            var tmp_instance = $( this ).waypoint({
                handler: function(direction) {
                    $( this ).children('process-image').toggleClass("fade-in");                        
                }
            });

            anchors.push( tmp_instance );

        } );

    } );

</script>
```

See if that helps to get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Lionel, I've slightly edited my HTML structure so the process-image unfortunately appears not as a lower div element but in a completely different DIV. Would I have to use a .find instead?

Comment: It would probably be better practice to keep it as a child so it can be more directly associated with the anchor element. If you do have to extract that `process-image` div though you can use `.next('.process-image')` or `prev('.process-image')` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Waypoints website http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/, you can accomplish the same thing as follows (waypoints will loop and fill your array with each instance).  I used this method on my site.

```
//within your document.ready function

var anchors = array();

anchors = $( '.trigger-anchor' ).waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        $(this).children('process-image').toggleClass("fade-in");
    }
});

//ALTERNATE METHOD
//you can also include your handler in the waypoint call

anchors = $( '.trigger-anchor' ).waypoint(function(){
    $(this).children('process-image').toggleClass("fade-in");
});
```